# Is It possible to Send Data Directly to Tally From Spring MVC Web Application with Rest API or with any other Way?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I wanted to build service which will update Data in Tally with the data sent from me using API.

I tried to find it on internet before implementation but only finding ways to extract data from tally, not of inserting or updating in tally.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!